# ng2-bootstrap btnRadio in angular 2 rc2 seed project. Two-way binding to ngModel is broken?

Tags: angular, radio-button, ng2-bootstrap, angular-seed

I'm trying to use the ng2-bootstrap radio-buttons in angular 2 rc2 seed project.
The following code works without any problems in our angular 2 rc1 project. Now I'm trying to create a seed project using `https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed` as the base and can't do it properly.

I use ng2-bootstrap radio-buttons directive in following way:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" [(ngModel)]="mode" btnRadio="EDITOR" uncheckable> 
     Editor 
</div>
```

I include the ng2-bootstrap and moment libraries in **seed.config.ts**. I have tried many variants (also with `ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap` etc.)

```
paths: {
  ...
  'ng2-bootstrap': `${this.NPM_BASE}/ng2-bootstrap/`,
  'moment': `${this.NPM_BASE}moment/`
},
packages: {
    ...
    'ng2-bootstrap': { main: "ng2-bootstrap.js", defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'moment': { main: "moment.js", defaultExtension: 'js' },
}
```

I import the following directives

```
import { BUTTON_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { ButtonRadioDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
```

And use this by my component

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: "editor",
  templateUrl: "editor.html",
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, BUTTON_DIRECTIVES, 
  CodeMirrorComponent, ButtonRadioDirective]
})
```

I build the project without any problems, but when i run the server, i obtain the following run time exception:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for ''
```

I'm sure the two-way binding to ngModel is broken here. I have used this code with rc1 bundles and without seed project. Now I'm not sure, what can be a problem - new angular version, or using a build system (in my case - gulp).

I hope anybody can help with advice. Many thanks in advance.

**Edited since 21.06.2016**

The versions of used packages are following:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.2",
  "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.2",
  "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.2",
  "@angular/forms": "^0.1.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.2",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.2",
  "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.6",
  "es6-module-loader": "^0.17.8",
  "core-js": "^2.4.0",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
  "systemjs": "0.19.26",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
  "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.17"
}
```

Comment: First slash is not necessary, I think, after BASE: ´'ng2-bootstrap': `${this.NPM_BASE}/ng2-bootstrap/`´

Comment: @LonelyProgrammer  you're right, but it doesn't fix the problem. It seems to be unnecessary to include ng2-bootstrap in the paths and packages. I have commented this lines and the application still works (also with early exception). Only the removing of `moment.js` from the packages/paths will broke the application.
My seed adds perhaps all imported (in typescript) packages from `node_modules` to the website. I can see it in developer tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all, i have found the problem and (temporally) solution. The problem was conflict between **ng2-bootstrap** and **angular.forms** (my version was 0.1.0). The problem is related to this issue https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/627 .

I don't use the angular forms now and have simple commented following lines in **main.ts**

```
//import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms/index';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
   //disableDeprecatedForms(),
   //provideForms(),
   APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
   {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
   }
]);
```

My code works now as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

**import**

```
import {AlertComponent} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
```

**path**

```
'ng2-bootstrap': `${this.NPM_BASE}ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.js`,
'moment/*': `${this.NPM_BASE}moment/*`,
```

**packages**

```
'ng2-bootstrap': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
moment: { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

Comment: It works now without any syntax errors, but still with `platform-browser.umd.js:2306 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for ''` exception.

Comment: Sorry, i don't see anything in this alert example, what can help me with my problem. 
i'm trying to use the radio buttons like in example: http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/buttons . I'm sure, angular gets stuck by using the binding to ngModel. If i don't use the two-way binding here, then i don't see any exceptions. But the functionality, what i need, is also away. What i can't understand, why the same piece of code was working in angular rc1 project?

Comment: maybe you need do something more, like in the example of the link above, click on TypeScript tab and see the AlertDemoComponent.